# What happens when an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am having issues understanding what happens when an exception gets thrown.

What happens to the exception that is thrown? What handles it to ensure that the program does not crash?

For instance,  in this example from [this tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076868/learn-java/how-the-java-virtual-machine-handles-exceptions.html), what will deal with the `ArithmeticException` that is thrown?

```
static int remainder(int dividend, int divisor)
    throws DivideByZeroException {
    try {
        return dividend % divisor;
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        throw new DivideByZeroException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial you link to emphasizes an important difference in what types of exceptions there are in Java, namely, whether an exception is *checked* or *unchecked*.

A **checked** exception is one that requires you as the developer to either catch it (i.e. deal with it), or declare it to be thrown and dealt with upstream.  The expectation is that you can recover from these sorts of exceptions.

An **unchecked** exception is one that may or may not crop up during the natural execution of the application, and may not introduce a natural way for the application to recover.  Catching them is often frowned upon since it is often indicative of poor design (you allowed a zero to make its way to a division operation, that's an illegal argument!).

In this scenario, because the method `remainder` declares that it is throwing a `DivideByZeroException`, all upstream callers of it *must* handle its exception either by:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        NitPickyMath.remainder(1, 0);
    } catch (DivideByZeroException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

...or by:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DivideByZeroException {
   NitPickyMath.remainder(1, 0);
}
```

The caveat to the latter form is that *nothing* will deal with the exception, and it will cause the application to crash.

---

> ...what will deal with the `ArithmeticException` that is thrown?

You already *are* dealing with it by placing it in a `catch` block.  You're simply re-throwing a checked exception to deal with the actual error resulting from dividing 1 into 0.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response it is appreciated. So basically the only way to "handle" an exception is to ensure it is caught somewhere in a catch block? Even if it is caught does it not mean that the application will still crash after the stack trace is printed?

Comment: @rni902:  ...or to declare it as thrown in a method signature.  Those are the only two ways to deal with a checked exception.  (If you don't do this, the compiler message says *pretty much* the same thing.)  As for it crashing after the stack trace is printed:  if you *don't* catch anything then yes it will crash; if you only print the stack trace *after* it's caught, it hasn't crashed.

Comment: Thanks, I guess what im trying to ask is, what happens when it is caught? I.e. "under the hood" Thats what i dont understand...